# How to generate clock in COCOTB?

Tags: python, cocotb

I am trying to verify a flash-based design using Cocotb (a Python-based framework) which I am new to it. I have always used verilog, SystemVerilog in the past. I am trying to generate the clock for a testbench.

I have tried going through the documentation. I see in the cocotb website where they have a clock class. I also see that I can use,something like, `cocotb.fork(clock(dut.clk,5000).start())` to generate the clock.

```
def directed_test(dut):

    cocotb.fork(Clock(dut.clk, 1000).start())
```

Is that all I need to do to generate a clock? The class Clock available on the cocotb documentation, should I simply import it and generate the clock by writing a statement as above inside a coroutine ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Learner.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, that's all you need. Replace the `clk` in `dut.clk` with the name of your clock signal if needed.
It's also nice to specify the `units` option, see https://cocotb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library_reference.html#cocotb.clock.Clock